# Accessing form posted values in PreExecute Method

Tags: symfony1

I have a form that submits to an action called update. I would like to validate the values before it gets processed. The problem is a correct value for the field depends upon values within other fields. It's not simple like is this number between 1 and 10. Hence I need a way to use preexecute method to dynamically configure the custom validator I've written.

The problem am having is I can't obtain the field values posted via the form

Comment: How about if you allow the validator for the dependent field to just 'pass' and use a post-validator to derive the correct value from the other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a post validator to do the job. Validate the fields that are simple with the field validators you have and then in the post validator (you have access to all field values) you execute the validation as complex as you want.

Some resource on that topic:

- http://tomislavsantek.iz.hr/2011/03/using-symfony-postvalidator/
- http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/conditional-validator
- http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms